# jQuery loaded dialog AJAX 'done' catch echoed result

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, jquery-callback

I have a page where I use `load` to load a dialog box. From that dialog box, I have jQuery in there that posts an ajax request to a PHP script. This all works fine. From the PHP I echo out the result and attempt to catch that on the `done` callback from this loaded dialog - but its not working. It updates the database, but I can't catch the echo. This works elsewhere in my site, but I can't get it working here. I think it might have something to do with the fact that this is coming from a 'loaded' dialog? Any help would be appreciated.

Code on original page initiating the load...

```
$('#edit_cats').click(function() {
   $('#overlay').show();
   $("#loader4").show().center();
   $('#dialogLoad').show().load('../../dialog/categories.php', {'site_user':'<?=$user_id?>','id':'<?=$blog['id']?>'});
});
```

AJAX code in the loaded dialog

```
$('.cat_input').bind('blur keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode !== 10 && e.keyCode !== 13) return;
   $(this).hide();
   var cat_title = $(this).val();
   var cat_id = $('.cat_selected').attr('id');

   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../system/process-cat-update.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { 'title':cat_title, 'cat_id':cat_id}
   }).done(function(data) {
      $('.cat_selected').find('.cat_title').html(data).show();
   });
});
```

PHP code

```
<?php 

include ('connect.php');
mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET category='".$_POST['title']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['cat_id']."' ");
echo $_POST['title'];

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't sending json in your response so `dataType: "json"` is incorrect, removing the `dataType` property should fix your problem. Also you aren't sanitizing you input so you are open to sql injection.

Comment: I haven't added security yet. What are you saying about dataType: "json" in the response? Im still a novice here ;)

Comment: @xtiaan your reponse is not `json` so remove the `dataType:'json`

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot, Musa. Simple!! If you post that as the answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help :)