# Use AJAX to load CI view pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to load a CodeIgniter view page using AJAX.

As described here, I've successfully generated the result in html, but the content is not loading (as in [Loading files via AJAX with CodeIgniter/MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380971/loading-files-via-ajax-with-codeigniter-mvc))

Ajax Code:

```
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST", 
          url: base_url + "like/load/" + interview_id,
          data:{name : name, email : email},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result){

              $('#loader').append(result);
          }

      });
```

PHP Code:

```
    public function load () 

{
    $this->load->view('interview/comment_view', $data_comments);
    $this->load->view('interview/associated_comment_view', $data_associated_comments);
    $this->load->view('interview/flag_comment_view', $data_flag_comments);

    $this->load->view('footer_view');

    die();
}
```

Using firebug, I see the response as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 charset=utf-8">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

</head>

<body>
<!-- dispalying the content I asked for -->
</body>
```

But for some reason is not showing in the 'loader' div I defined. Any advice will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266414/jquery-loaded-dialog-ajax-done-catch-echoed-result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112628/my-ajax-post-is-coming-up-as-an-error-even-though-i-am-returning-200

Comment: Ah great! Voted up your answer there. One more thing: can I load more than 1 view files here? It seems I could only load 1 for now...

Comment: I fixed it as you mentioned, but for some reason the whole page keeps loading a blank page after the right content is loaded. Advice needed!